# Android: Problem with SpanableString and ListView

Tags: android

I have a problem, I have a custom ListVie, inside each row I have a TextView and other things. Inside the the TextView I have a Spannable text with a url open behaviour. My problem is I have a itemClick event for the listview too. If I activate de LinkMovementMethod for the textView, the itemclick event dont work.

Any solution? work arround?

Thanks,

flipper83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any ItemClick event on the ListView, if the list item contains any focusable item.

Try setting the focusable property of textview to false.

HTH !

Comment: it's works!! I have tried setClickable false, but I haven't triyed this, I feel some stupid. Thanks.

Now if click out of span selected text dont work the itemClick, but I dont need it those. Thanks for all.